# The dependency `SinchVerification-Swift` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

I am trying to use SinchVerification in my IOS app. However after I do `pod install` I get this error:

> The dependency `SinchVerification-Swift` is not used in any concrete target.

What does this mean? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your pod after do

```
target 'Your-Project' do

pod 'SinchVerification-Swift'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is usually caused by lost the target in Podfile. And if the Podfile is not in the same dir wiht .xcodeproj, you have also to add `project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'` to specify it.

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SinchVerification-Swift'
target 'your target name.'
```